# i understand javascript to an intermediate level but still can't understand angular 4 logic

Tags: javascript, angular

i am confused, i tried watching several video tutorials on youtube on both angular 2 and 4 as well as taking the angular 1.x course on codecademy, both courses mentioned that i need to have at least a basic understanding of javascript in order to keep up, which i do have btw to an intermediate extent even, but for some reason on those courses the teachers keep mentioning stuff/jargon/logic i haven't heard of before and they talk about it as if i should've learned it by now, am i missing something here?

Comment: Can you tell us some of the jargon and logic used?  I don't think you have a problem with the syntax, but Angular uses some patterns and conventions that you may be unfamiliar with.

Comment: for starters MVC, $scope and routes and the syntax used to define them

Comment: MVC = [model view controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller); [$scope](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp); routes are ways to navigate between screens in the application without reloading pages (like Gmail and not like yahoo.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to understand that AngularJS (version 1.x) and Angular (versions 2 through 4.3.x which is current) are very different frameworks. They solve the same fundamental problems, and there are similarities, but the v2 and on versions are a complete rewrite, so if you're just learning now, I would suggest you stick to Angular, which is version 2+ and avoid the 1.x version entirely as you'll just confuse things.

Second, Angular is a framework that leverages JavaScript as well as making use of HTML and CSS, so if you're rusty on any of those, it's worth getting a grounding in them before you start as that will help you find a comfortable foundation on which to build your Angular knowledge.

I would recommend starting from scratch and taking a number of courses that may cover things you already think you know, but the refresher will be valuable.

Something like https://teamtreehouse.com is very useful, you can sign up for a month or two - it's fairly inexpensive, and there are lots of intro through advance course tracks that will ground you in JavaScript, HTML and CSS. There's also an Angular track, but I wouldn't recommend it as it's not exactly comprehensive, but it may be worth going through just for the exposure.

Once you've got your head wrapped around the core concepts, I would recommend https://ultimateangular.com - it's for pay, but you won't find a more accessible, clear and useful set of course material for Angular anywhere. Make sure to stay on the Angular 2 track, and you can go through the fundamentals course for $120± and see how that goes, and then pay the difference to get into some of the bundles - there's a very useful TypeScript course (TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, and it's what Angular is written with, so I would recommend getting a good understanding of that as it will make reading Angular docs and sample code much easier).

You can read all the blogs and free how to's you can find, but without a solid foundation to build on, you're going to waste a lot of time being frustrated and feeling lost, so I can't overstate how valuable a good, focused training program will be in getting you running and productive in the technology.

Once you've got that base, and you're working on a project where you've got actual source code you need help with, that's when turning to StackOverflow and asking specific questions about things you've already researched and tried working through will get you the most valuable feedback.

Comment: thanks for the very informative reply, i'll try looking into typescript, and any udemy courses on angular you can recommend that are any good? i am sort of low on funds right now and rely on the discounts udemy gives from time to time

Comment: Any of Asim Hussain's courses on JavaScript and Angular on Udemy are worth your time, and they do have $15 sales all the time, and his book is available free on CodeCraft - https://codecraft.tv. Good luck! Enjoy! It's quite a journey!

Comment: right on! thank you